# qooxdoo : XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, xampp, qooxdoo

I have a qooxdoo project that fetches JSON from an online server using the following codes:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/json.php?q=parameter_here";
var store = new qx.data.store.Json(url,"GET", "text/plain");
store.addListener("changeModel", function(ev) {
    console.log("changeModel()");
    console.log("getData", ev.getData());
});
store.addListener("error", function(ev) {
        console.log("error", ev.getData());
    });
    store.addListener("changeState", function(ev) {
    console.log("state", ev.getData());
});
```

I'm using iMac, and the local path is `/Users/SomeUser/Path/To/index.html`

I tried to load the `index.html` in Chrome browser as usual, but failed, as Chrome blocks the Javascript as `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. After I read the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224017/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-in-chrome-why), I know I have to host it in a web server. Therefore I set up a XAMPP for this site.

Since my XAMPP has few existing Alias, I add a new Alias for this site, as follow:

```
<Directory "/Users/SomeUser/Path/To">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /myalias "/Users/SomeUser/Path/To"
```

When I set up the Alias like this, 403 Forbidden is reported. Then, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807317/fixing-403-forbidden-on-alias-directory-with-apache) on SO, but the answers didn't help. Still 403 Forbidden.

*My goal is to load the site in local XAMPP server.* What did I miss? When I upload the folder to a web server online, it works fine.

In XAMPP Apache `error_log`, it shows:

> [Fri Apr 19 17:51:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission
>   denied: access to /myalias/index.html denied

For the file, its permission is:

```
drwxr-xrwx  7 SomeUser  staff  238 Apr  2 16:48 .
```

Note: I don't want to change the Chrome launch options to override the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that all you have to do is to go to your xampp/mamp install folder, locate the htdocs folder and inside of it create a new folder with your project(say test) then access it in your browser like: `http://localhost/test/` right ?

Comment: Documents in other Alias and documents in the `htdocs` directory works fine.

Comment: maybe a blind shot, but what if you create a local domain (say whatever.com) and map it to 127.0.0.1 ?   In windows you would map this in hosts file, in linux in /etc/hosts in macos i am not sure, but should be something similar. Then access it instead of accessing localhost. This might do the trick.

Comment: tried but it is the same 403 Forbidden. Mac OS X has hosts file as other Linux-based OS does ( located at `/etc/hosts` ).

Comment: what's happening if you chmod -R 0777 the-folder ? Under which user your apache is running? try chown -R apacheUser:apacheUser the-folder

Comment: my Apache ( XAMPP's one) is running with `root` account.