# Is it possible to use alias directory in htdocs of xampp on mac?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed Xampp on mac and I'm going to run my web application on local, which located on `"/Data/MyApp/App"`.

I know I should put source codes inside `htdocs`.
So I created an alias of `"App"` by `right click -> Make Alias` and put it to `"Applications/Xampp/htdocs/"`. I changed alias name `test`.
When I run `localhost/test` on chrome browser, I see empty screen but downloads unknown file `test`.

Instead, I paste whole sources(`App`) to `htdocs` with name `test2` and `localhost/test2` shows me correct screen according to the `index.php` inside of `test2`. Just note that file structures of `test` and `test2` are exactly same.

```
Applications/Xampp/htdocs/test(alias)/index.php         // not working
Applications/Xampp/htdocs/test2(real folder)/index.php  // work well
```

What's wrong with this?
Should I set something for making alias folder work inside `htdocs`?

Comment: You need to include pertinent configuration sections and [in general adhere to these standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I added some more infos. Please help me for the solution.

Comment: Also, just my strong advice, but avoid xampp or any other workstation polluting environments.  Go with vagrant/virtualbox or docker.  You'll have an environment that can match production, which can also be easily turned on and off, as well as getting around problems that can occur with localhost environments like cookie setting.

Comment: Also please provide the apache conf for the vhost, as well as ls -lathF on the directory.  I believe your question can be answered by doing one or more of the following; -making sure the execute bit is set on the alias directory, making sure that followsymlinks is set for the directory statement in the apache conf.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807317/fixing-403-forbidden-on-alias-directory-with-apache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after struggling a few hours, I found what I was wrong. I removed alias folder which I created by `right click -> Make Alias` and created new one with this command.

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs
ln -s /Data/MyApp/App test
```

I'm not sure what was wrong with original alias.

Comment: Indeed! Shame Alias doesn't have the same effect :( But check out SymbolicLinker as an alternative app for Mac: https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker/releases

Answer (score 0):

An **Alias** has to point to a real location on your server. For example you can create the **/test** alias for your real working location **test2** like this:

```
Alias /test Applications/Xampp/htdocs/test2/
```

Restart apache and then you will be able to access http://localhost/test

For more information you should read how an apache alias works and how to define it:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: No, I didn't want this way. The alias of source should work originally.